# Should I always use "contents" when talking of things contained in something?

Tags: word-usage

When giving the meaning of *content* used as "the things that are contained in something," [the OALD uses the plural form](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/content). Does that mean *contents* should always be used in that case?

> He tipped the contents of the bag onto the table.

I understand that in the case of books (except when talking of sections of a book), speech, or programme, I should use *content*.

Surprisingly for me, the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* doesn't have any example of sentences containing "the content of the suitcase" or "the content of the bottle" or "the content of the bag."

I can find *content* used in the following phrases, though.

- The content of the information
- The content of the showdown between protagonist and antagonist
- The content of the particular text
- The content of the bill
- The content of the error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used in either plural or singular form. The singular form is used if what is within the container is uncountable/a mass noun. Either the singular or plural can be used to discuss unknown content.

> The *content* of the film is not appropraite for children.
>   The clear plastic box showed its *contents* clearly.
>   The *content* of the bottle was a mix of apple and cranberry juice.